# disable password protected page for logged users

Tags: posts, pages, users

Is it possible to add hooks on function.php for disable password protected page for back-end users (logged users)?

I use beaver builder and when i modify page or post I need always to put the password of the page before to access to the builder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disable the post password protection for (some) users**

You can try the [`post_password_required`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_password_required/) filter (4.7+) to override it for logged in users:

```
add_filter( 'post_password_required', function( $returned, $post )
{
    // Override it for logged in users:
    if( $returned && is_user_logged_in() )
        $returned = false;

    return $returned;
}, 10, 2 );
```

or disable it for users with a given capability ( e.g. *manage_options*) :

```
add_filter( 'post_password_required', function( $returned, $post )
{
    // Override it for users with the 'manage_options' capability
    if( $returned && current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        $returned = false;

    return $returned;
}, 10, 2 );
```

We could target a given post type with:

```
add_filter( 'post_password_required', function( $returned, $post )
{
    // Target protected posts only
    if( ! $returned )
        return $returned;

    // Target logged in users only
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return $returned;

    // Target 'page' post type only
   if( 'page' !== get_post_type( $post ) )
        return $returned;

   // Override 
   return false;

}, 10, 2 );
```

**Remove 'Protected' text from protected post titles**

To remove the prepended *Protected* from the title, we can adjust the *protected title format*, for logged in users, with the [protected_title_format](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/protected_title_format/) filter:

```
add_filter( 'protected_title_format', function( $format, $post )
{
    if( is_user_logged_in() )
        $format = '%s';

    return $format;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: It's works great thanks! is it possible to disable password protected page for a specific user role?

Comment: yes,  I updated the answer @sampaii

Comment: Thanks very much @birgire. I have an other question at this link if you have an idea : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/268228/custom-protected-password-page-with-acf .  Thanks again for your help