# Custom protected password page with ACF

Tags: customization, custom-field, pages, advanced-custom-fields, password

I need some help if it's possible. Each page of my website are protected with a password, i use protected password page.

Page link : http://builder.depretz.com/onepage-hotel[image]

You can see the custom code i use.

CUSTOM CODE :

```
#custom password page

function my_password_form() {
    global $post;
    $label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
    $o = '<form action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=postpass', 'login_post' ) ) . '" method="post" style="font-size:56px;margin:20px;text-align:center;">
    ' . __( "" ) . '
    <img src="http://builder.depretz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/mb.png" border="0" />
    <label for="' . $label . '">' . __( "" ) . ' </label><input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password"  style="background: #ffffff; border:1px solid #999; color:#333333; padding:10px;margin:auto;width:40%;height: 50px;"  size="20" maxlength="20" /><input style="width:40%;height:50px;Background:##263bda;border:#d8c217" type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr__( "GO" ) . '" />
    </form>
    <p style="font-size:14px;margin:10px;text-align:center;">THE PASSWORD IS SENSITIVE TO THE CASE  </p>

    ';
    return $o;
}
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'my_password_form' );

#remove title on protected page

function remove_protected_in_title($title) {
    return '';
}

add_filter('private_title_format', 'remove_protected_in_title');
add_filter('protected_title_format', 'remove_protected_in_title');

?>
```

I want to use ACF (Advanced Custom Field) to create personalization background for each page. so creating a custom field box on admin page and link it with the background of protected page. (like the attachment picture).

[image]

Each page will have it's own background on the protected page. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Can you give me idea about custom code to add on function.php for that?